# Auto update photo album based on tags in Picasa

Tags: photo-gallery, picasa

Hi everyone picasa users

I am reorganizing my photo collection by moving to one folder per year structure and rename photos by date. I'd like to group photos in albums based on tags, for example I'd like an album for 2014 summer holiday. I can create such albums but is it possible to update them?

What if I add a tag to a new photo? will it appear on the right album?

Thanks for your help

Paco

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from the Picasa Google Forum I got the answer. In Picasa 3.9 there is an experimental feature to use tags as albums, under the "experimental tools" menu.

So, any new tagged photo will appear on the album.